# Running Python Program in Linux Terminal- Unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, linux, ide, raspbian, eof

This is the last few lines of my code:

```
except UnknownValueError as uve:
   engine.say("Something went wrong. Please try again.")
   engine.runAndWait()
   wwlisten = sr.Recognizer()
   with sr.Microphone as Microphone:
      wakeword = wwlisten.listen(Microphone)
```

My issue is this (I'm using Raspbian by the way): When I run the code in terminal, it says 'unexpected EOF while parsing'. I know what this means, but this is caused by two things: One is that whenever I save my code in a text editor or Python IDE, a new line is generated. The second is that the line really doesn't exist when after I've saved the code and I get the error anyway. Does anyone know how to resolve any of these two issues? I threw the code in just in case you guys wanted to take a look to make sure. 
Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, trailing new lines are not a problem (at least, not a critical one), and AFAIK they don't cause `unexpected EOF while parsing` errors...

Comment: Welcome to SO. how do you run the code? How come you get some lines added - what lines? If you run it as `python -c`? Then you need to have the string in different escape characters i.e. `python -c ' code with some ".."  ' `

Comment: @JanSila thank you for your suggestion, and sorry for the delayed response. I'm not totally sure what the problem was but I just kept running it over and over and everything is running smoothly now. Thank you though!

Comment: Ok, thats cool.

Comment: Maybe you should close the question somehow. I would bet it was caused by a mixup of string escaping